# Random variable generation in a Computation class

Tags: java, arrays, random

I am trying to run a class that performs calculations from data obtained from a random variable generator class. What I want is that 3 random variables be generated at any given time, then all calculation in that class be performed without another set of random variables be generated. Once all calculations have been performed then a new set of random variables can be generated. The Computation class is as shown below :

```
 public class Computation {



   public int meltTemp;
 //public void mTemp;
  public int mouldTemp;
public int setTemp;
public int Q;
public int volume;
public double Cp;
public int actualMouldTemp;
public double dT;
public int AMT ;//= Math.abs(dT);
public double mTemp;


  public Hashtable catalogue1;


   protected void setup() {
   //create Hashtable
   catalogue1 = new Hashtable();

    }



public double getAnswer() {


        int rand1[] = new int[3];
        int input [] = new int [2];

        ControlGUI par = new ControlGUI ();
        //input = ControlGUI.getArray();
        //catalogue am = new catalogue();



        RandomVariableGenerator var = new RandomVariableGenerator();
        rand1 = RandomVariableGenerator.getRand();
        //int rand[] = Arrays.copyOf(rand1, rand1.length);  

        meltTemp = 245;

        System.out.println("Melt Temp is  : "+ meltTemp);


        actualMouldTemp = (int)  ((0 - 51.4)+(0.302 * meltTemp) +(1.64 * rand1[0])+(0.201 * rand1[1]));

        System.out.println("The actual mould temperature is :" +actualMouldTemp + " Degrees celcius" );


        return actualMouldTemp;

 }



  public int getDiff(){

     Computation amg = new Computation();


   double  result[] = new double [4]; {

     setTemp = 55;
     dT = (actualMouldTemp - setTemp);
     AMT = (int) Math.abs(dT);

     System.out.println("The temperature difference is : "+ AMT);

     return AMT;
     }
      }
```

The next method to try and use the generated variables is getHeatingTime1() which needs rand1[2]  for the tank volume:

```
  public double getHeatingTime1(){

   Computation jose = new Computation();

   int [] Results = new int [4];
   Results [0] = AMT;
   //Results [] = Computation.class;

   Q = 3; //heating in kW
   Cp = 4.2; //Specific heat capacity of water
   volume = 6; 

  //AMT = 
   System.out.println("AMT IS "+ Results [0]);
   long HT1 = (long) ((volume*Cp*Results [0])/Q);

   return HT1;

   }

  public double getHeatingTime2(){
 int Results [] = new int [4] ;   
   Computation cr7 = new Computation();
   //double dT = cr7.getDiff();

   Q = 9; //heating in kW
   Cp = 4.2; //Specific heat capacity of water
   volume = 6;
   //AMT = 7;
   System.out.println("AMT IS "+ Results [1]);
   long HT2 = (long) ((volume*Cp*Results [1])/Q);
   return HT2;
 }

public double getHeatingTime3(){
 int Results [] = new int [4];   
 //double AMT = getDiff();       
   Computation jt = new Computation();

   //double dT = jt.getDiff();
  // AMT = 7;
   Q = 18; //heating in kW
   Cp = 4.2; //Specific heat capacity of water
   volume = 6;
    System.out.println("AMT IS "+ Results [1]);
   long HT3 = (long) ((volume*Cp*Results [1])/Q);

   return HT3;
   }

   public double getCoolingTime(){
     // double CT = 0;  
    Computation nvh = new Computation();

    int rand1[] = new int[3];
    int rand[] = Arrays.copyOf(rand1, rand1.length);  
    //RandomVariableGenerator var = new RandomVariableGenerator();
   //rand1 = Computation;
     mouldTemp = 55;

       System.out.println("Rand 0 is "+ rand1[0]);
       System.out.println("Rand 1 is "+ rand1[1]);
       System.out.println("Rand 2 is "+ rand1[2]);

     double CT =  ((0.5/rand[2])*((mouldTemp - rand1[0])/(rand1[1] - mouldTemp)));
       double CTA = Math.abs(CT);
       return CTA;

   }
  }
```

The Random variable generator class is as shown below:

```
  public class RandomVariableGenerator {

 public static int[] getRand (){
    int rand[] = new int [3];

    Random r = new Random ();
    int myRandomNumber = 0;
    //for (int i=0; i < 1 ; i++)
    myRandomNumber = r.nextInt(15) + 5;
    System.out.println("Chilled water temperature:" + myRandomNumber);
    rand[0] = myRandomNumber;

    Random rn = new Random ();
    int myNumber = 0;
    // (for int i=0; i < 1; i++)
    myNumber = rn.nextInt(25) + 50; 
    System.out.println("Heated water temperature:" + myNumber);
    rand[1]= myNumber;

    Random rm = new Random ();
    int myRandNumber = 0;
    // (for int i=0; i < 1; i++)
    myRandNumber = rm.nextInt(2) + 6; 
    System.out.println("Tank Volume:" + myRandNumber);
    rand[2]= myRandNumber;

     return rand;
 }    


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make all of the 3 random variables private and to the class, not the function. Then, when you need a new set call a function that resets them.

For example:

```
public class MyClass{
//replace these with the actual types/variables you need
int var1;
double var2;
double var3;    

/**
*Call this function when you need a new set of variables
**/
public void resetVariables(){
    //Change this to the random class you would prefer to use
    Random random = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
    var1 = random.nextInt();
    var2 = random.nextDouble();
    var3 = random.nextDouble();
}

//put your other functions here except remove the declarations for var1, var2, and var3
/*
    ex.
    public int myFunction(){
        Random random = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
        int var1 = random.nextInt();
        return var1 * 2;
    }

    becomes

    public int myFunction(){
        // use the global variable instead of the function's variable
        return var1 * 2;
    }
*/

}
```

Comment: I sorry but Im very new with Java and I do not know how to do that. Please help.

Comment: Thanks for the response. var1, var2 and var3 replace my Random values?? How do i call my random values without using the timer?

Comment: Also how do I access the random values on other methods??

Comment: Just use them as you would any variable. They will automatically be there as long as it is in the same class. There is no timer involved, simply call resetVariables() when you need a new set of variables.

Comment: Thanks for the response I called resetVariables from my getAnswer method and put var1 and var2 in the calculation for actualMouldTemp but var1 and var2 re seemigly zeros and are giving me a false answer. Please show me how exactly on my code the reserVariables() method is implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Declare an instance int vector to hold the three values at object (instance) level (rndVars[3])

```
public class Computation {

   public int meltTemp;
 //public void mTemp;
  public int mouldTemp;
public int setTemp;
public int Q;
public int volume;
public double Cp;
public int actualMouldTemp;
public double dT;
public int AMT ;//= Math.abs(dT);
public double mTemp;

private int [] rndVars = new int[3];

...
```

Have a public method setRandomVars() you can call whenever you need the 3 values to be reset.

```
public void setRandomVars(){
    rndVars[0] = RandomVariableGenerator.getRand();
    rndVars[1] = RandomVariableGenerator.getRand();
    rndVars[2] = RandomVariableGenerator.getRand();
}
```

Comment: Hi. So I call this function from my methods??

Comment: Hi. The method works when I want to get the values in the initial step on getAnswer. I am now failing to then use the other generated value in the other heating methods. It is giving me a zero value. Hiw do I fix this?